# How to obtain GetProcAdress and LoadLibrary without them?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, dll, reverse-engineering

Assume that i have no import .lib libraries
and i want everything to do in raw, by manual writing
calls (like in assembly, or pure c)

GetProcAdress LoadLibrary are part of winapi dll's
In general to load dlls and to obtain a pointers
to functions i need to call those two, but as i 
dont get them what can i use to obtain them?

This is a bit like paradox, probably it can be resolved by some other mechanisms but here my lack of knowledge shows, and i dont know what this mechanism is, Can someone explain it?

Comment: You seem to have a catch-22: You need function from the kernel32 DLL, but to get those functions you need functions from the kernel32 DLL. To resolve your problem you *must* link with the system libraries, there's really no other way. And I don't actually see the use-case for not linking with the system libraries.

Comment: but as far as i know statically linking generates just coding stub that also uses Loadlibrary and GetPRocAdress

Comment: @user2214913: Even if your program is statically linked you still will have dynamic references to `kernel32.dll` and `user32.dll`. The static part applies to compiler and user libraries, not to system ones.

Comment: This sounds awfully like malware

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I'm guessing you're the one who downvoted the question and my answer? You should seriously take a break from policing this site. I've done exactly what the OP here is mentioning purely for the sake of education/learning and without ever even having had the intention to release malware. (Hell, I don't think I could write one even if I wanted to.)

Comment: @Mehrdad Nope, I've not voted here. Please don't make assumptions.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Okay sorry. I assumed you did since you had the negative commend under it, and I didn't see any other reason why anyone would downvote it. I guess my comment above applies to whoever did so then.

Comment: @Mehrdad I wouldn't get too concerned about the voting. People vote for all sorts of different reasons. There's nothing much you can do about it. I don't think either Q nor A deserve a downvote here, but perhaps we've just had some drive by voting. It happens. Nothing to be done about it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have actually managed to do this before. It is indeed possible. The solution is to basically implement `LdrGetDllHandle` *manually* and use it to search for `LdrLoadDll`/`LdrUnloadDll` and `LdrGetProcedureAddress` inside `NTDLL` by getting a pointer to the process's `PEB_LDR_DATA` data structure via `NtCurrentPeb`, which is a macro that reads the FS or GS CPU registers.
Once you have pointers to those three functions, you can use them to load additional DLLs that you need.

I'm not going to post the code for you, but if you look at the source code of ReactOS, you should be able to gradually figure out how to implement this -- I think these should be enough pointers (no pun intended) to get you started. :)

Comment: Why in the world did someone downvote my answer? Is it because you didn't like the question and therefore thought I shouldn't answer it?

Comment: on stack there are many lamas today, its quite oftan if i state a bit to much advanced (or to low lewel or to anything.. ) question they downwote it - lamas rule

Comment: But do the compilers like GCC do the same trick ? You know if i will link with static import libs I suspect the code stub must have some way to provide those linked dll pointers to the app - how it is done there?

Comment: @user2214913: No, static imports are completely different. The operating system loads statically imported modules for you before it executes your program. This is for if you wanted to do this yourself without having static imports at all.

Comment: you mean windows loader do that and fills the export import tables? how loader knows which dlls to load this way?

Comment: @user2214913: I'm confused what you're saying. What a linker does is it simply finds the LIB that corresponds to the external function and then places a little "note" inside the executable's "Import table" saying that the function must be from the corresponding DLL. The Windows loader then knows this DLL must be loaded before the program runs, so it does that before calling your main method.

Comment: well that would probably explain the thing - my suspiction is: GCC generates exe with empty import tables of pointers and windows loader fills this on load time .. If so i accept the answer as this was an info i needed

Comment: Yes that's basically it.

Comment: @user So far as I can tell, you have no need at all to do what is described in this answer. I suspect that you have asked the wrong question.

Answer (score 8):

The following works on the assumption that mainCRTStartup() is called from inside kernel32.dll.
It uses the return address to locate the start of the module, and from there searches its EAT for GetProcAddress().

```
#include <windows.h>

static HMODULE findModuleBase( void *ptr )
{
  ULONG_PTR addr = (ULONG_PTR)ptr;
  addr &= ~0xffff;
  const UINT32 *mod = (const UINT32*)addr;
  while( mod[0]!=0x00905a4d ) // MZ.. header
    mod -= 0x4000; // 0x10000/4
  return( (HMODULE)mod );
}

#define REL_PTR( base,ofs ) ( ((PBYTE)base)+ofs )
static void *findGetProcAddress( HMODULE mod )
{
  PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER idh = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)mod;
  PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS inh = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)REL_PTR( idh,idh->e_lfanew );
  PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY ied =
    (PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY)REL_PTR( idh,inh->OptionalHeader.
        DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT].VirtualAddress );
  DWORD *names = (DWORD*)REL_PTR( idh,ied->AddressOfNames );
  unsigned int i;
  for( i=0; i<ied->NumberOfNames; i++ )
  {
    const UINT32 *name32 = (const UINT32*)REL_PTR( idh,names[i] );
    const UINT16 *name16 = (const UINT16*)name32;
    const UINT8 *name8 = (const UINT8*)name32;
    if( name32[0]!=0x50746547 || // GetP
        name32[1]!=0x41636f72 || // rocA
        name32[2]!=0x65726464 || // ddre
        name16[6]!=0x7373 ||     // ss
        name8[14]!=0x00 )
      continue;
    WORD *ordinals = (WORD*)REL_PTR( idh,ied->AddressOfNameOrdinals );
    DWORD *funcs = (DWORD*)REL_PTR( idh,ied->AddressOfFunctions );
    return( REL_PTR(idh,funcs[ordinals[i]]) );
  }
  return( NULL );
}

#ifdef __MINGW32__
#define RETURN_ADDRESS() __builtin_return_address(0)
#else
#define RETURN_ADDRESS() _ReturnAddress()
#endif
void mainCRTStartup( void )
{
  HMODULE kernel = findModuleBase( RETURN_ADDRESS() );

  typedef LPVOID WINAPI func_GetProcAddress( HMODULE,LPCSTR );
  func_GetProcAddress *fGetProcAddress = findGetProcAddress( kernel );

  typedef HMODULE WINAPI func_LoadLibraryA( LPCSTR );
  typedef VOID WINAPI func_ExitProcess( UINT );
  func_LoadLibraryA *fLoadLibraryA = fGetProcAddress( kernel,"LoadLibraryA" );
  func_ExitProcess *fExitProcess = fGetProcAddress( kernel,"ExitProcess" );

  typedef int func_printf( const char*,... );
  HMODULE msvcrt = fLoadLibraryA( "msvcrt.dll" );
  func_printf *f_printf = fGetProcAddress( msvcrt,"printf" );
  f_printf( "is this working?\n" );

  fExitProcess( 1 );
}
```

Comment: Could You explain two things 1) may I assume my code is called from under kernal32.dll ? (is the mainCRTStartup() the forst one?) 2) do the win compilers like GCC (I mean winapi aps generated by them) do such trick to get acces to those function that then thay can use to dynamically link dlls? (this is the main point of my question i dont understand: some damn handle to LoadLibrary GetProcAdrr is needed before i can use them, how such apps do that?)

Comment: tnx anyway for the code its interesting

Comment: Yes, mainCRTStartup() is the first one.
The apps created by gcc don't need any trick, they just use .a files (which are just their equivalent of .lib files).

Comment: but those lib code stubs must use LoadLibrary/GetProcAddres how do they get them?

Comment: You should read up on [PE internals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx), in particular the [Import Address Table](http://sandsprite.com/CodeStuff/Understanding_imports.html).